How to configure host in postfix
I am setting up Postfix to use with Spamassasin for filtering emails in my regional language. I am following [this article1 to setup Postfix.
But at the following lines, I am confused. I am not a Linux user and I am not able to understand what to do.

Update or add the following lines:
mydomain = yourdomain.com
myorigin = $mydomain 
inet_interfaces = all 
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
home_mailbox = Maildir/


I tried to write my local laptop server name and it didn't work out.

Include the whole question into question, that should include your configuration, your logs and other diagnostic information and so on. It's good you linked to the article you were using for inspiration, but to help you with your problem we need to see your work as you've done it, not the textbook you were using (not mentioning the questionable quality of that "textbook"; Postfix has its own documentation and it's of exemplar quality, use it before asking). Also, text information should be put as text, don't use screenshots.
